# Eclipse Parallel Debugger SDM error

Tags: eclipse, parallel-processing, ubuntu-12.04, mpi

I have a freshly installed  "Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers" running on Ubuntu 12.04.

*Eclipse Platform: 4.3.2.v20140221-1852*,

*EPP Parallel Bundle: 2.0.2.20140224-0000*,

*Parallel Tools Platform: 7.0.4.201402121320*

I have created with the New Project Wizard an MPI Pi C++ Project, which compiles and runs correctly.

When I try to debug it with SDM I get the following error:

**Path '/usr/local/bin/sdm' not found**

Which seems to be true cause when I check /usr/local/bin/ there is no sdm folder indeed.

I read this wiki: http://wiki.eclipse.org/PTP/release_notes/7.0

There is a section on how to install SDM manually for remote systems. It tells me to go to this site:

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ptp/updates/kepler/

and download the **ptp-sdm-7.0.4.zip** file. But when I try to download it, I get to this page:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/ptp/builds/kepler/nightly/ptp-sdm-7.0.4.zip

,which basically says: **FILE UNAVAILABLE**.

I have checked the Eclipse Kepler download site: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ I wasn't able to locate the package there.

Actually according to the wiki I shouldn't need to manually install SDM anyway.

Did anyone else come across this? If so are there any solutions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading the new version [here](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ptp/builds/luna/nightly/)